# Read csv file from directory

Tags: r, csv, directory

How to read a csv file from directory? I am trying these code to read data

```
getwd()
# [1] "C:/Users/Riya Sajid/Downloads/New folder (2)"
setwd("C:/Users/Riya Sajid/Downloads/New folder (2)")
getwd()
# [1] "C:/Users/Riya Sajid/Downloads/New folder (2)"
```

Comment: If your file is in your current working directory `read.csv("YourFileName.csv")`

Comment: Those functions do not read data.  Have a look at `?read.csv`

Comment: Have you tried searching "how to import data r" perhaps? This is the first hit that comes up for me: http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/data-frame/data-import

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In windows, '\' is translation operator, you need to use

```
"C://Users//Riya Sajid//Downloads//New folder"
```